# Openfiledialog problem with File Description Error

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015, openfiledialog

Iam using VS2015 - Windows Forms. When I click my Browse Button the OpenFileDialog Works good. But Suppose once I Re-click the button after to refresh the form data's, the OpenFileDialog simply hang-up.

I can't understand my problem.. Any of the superiors can guide me?

```
MyFileNameStr = String.Empty;
openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\\";
openFileDialog1.Filter = "(*.xlsx)|*.xls| All files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Your Attachment File :- ";
openFileDialog1.FileName = "";
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK && openFileDialog1.FileName.Length>0) {
    String MyDrawingFile = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    myDataGrid1.CurrentRow.Cells["MyExcel_file"].Value = Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    MyFileNameStr = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName.ToString();
    MyFileNameStrs = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName.ToString().Split('_');
}
```

Thanks Again

Comment: There are multiple explanations for this, the question doesn't help us figure out which one is the correct one.  What does "file description error" mean?

Comment: Does your main method have the [STAThread]  attribute?

Comment: Do you have an OpenFileDialog Component on a Form? Are you referencing  `Microsoft.Win32`?  Try with `using (var ofd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog()) { ...rest of the code... }`. You should also mention where this code is called from.

Comment: ,,,and you don't need to check this `&& openFileDialog1.FileName.Length>0`.

Comment: with Form Declaration                                                                          OpenFileDialog OpenFileDialog1=new OpenFileDialog()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the few more below codes for file descriptions, then it works good.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "D:\\";
openFileDialog1.Title = "Select Your Attachment File :- ";

openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
openFileDialog1.Filter = "exe files | *.exe|All files (*.*)|*.*";

openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

openFileDialog1.ReadOnlyChecked = true;
openFileDialog1.ShowReadOnly = true;

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
MyDrawingFile = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(openFileDialog1.FileName).ToString();
MyFileNameStr = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName).ToString();
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

this is due to 
if you click on button and browse a file then the process is running on your excel file.
if you again click on button the process is busy with your excel file and app will get hang.